# JobScheduler Android- setRequiresCharging not working

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I am new to jobscheduler api. My requirement is to start the jobservice when the device is plugged into charging. This is the below config

```
JobScheduler jobScheduler =
                (JobScheduler) getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        jobScheduler.schedule(new JobInfo.Builder(1,
                new ComponentName(this, MyService.class))
                .setRequiresCharging(true)
                .setPeriodic(3000)
                .setPersisted(true)
                .build());
```

This not working for me. It is working only for setPeriodic event . I have tried by plugin and plug out mobile. can any body help on this?

This is my service class

```
public class MyService extends JobService {

    private List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private int counter = 1;
    JobScheduler jobScheduler;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        addResultValues(jobParameters);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)this.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE );
        jobScheduler.cancelAll();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"device stoppppppppppp..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    private void addResultValues(JobParameters jobParameters ) {
        Random random = new Random();
        List<String> input = Arrays.asList("Linux", "Android","iPhone","Windows7" );
        resultList.add(input.get(random.nextInt(3)) + " " + counter++);
        if (counter == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            counter = 0;
        }
        Log.e("service",resultList.size()+"::::::");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"device charging..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        jobFinished(jobParameters, false);

    }
}
```

My Manifest file

```
<service android:name=".MyService"
        android:label="app_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
        >
    </service>
```

Comment: I see that you have a period of 3 minutes. If you look at the JobInfo code, MIN_PERIOD_MILLIS is set to 15 minutes. Anything that is set below this period will actually use 15 minutes. Could it be just taking 15 minutes instead of the expected 3 minutes?

Comment: *Your period is actually set to 3 seconds, not 3 minutes.